Can a Rational Function on a Curve have no k-rational Zeros?
I want to compute the divisor of $Y/Z$ on the curve $X = V(Y^2Z+YZ^2 - X^3 - XZ^2 - Z^3)$ in projective space over $GF(7)$. I can find the poles very easily, if we substitute $Z = 0$ into our variety above, we get
\begin{align*}
X^3 = 0
\end{align*}
Which has three solutions, $[0:1:0], [0:1:1], [0:0:1]$ but $Z$ must be zero so our pole is $[0:1:0]$ at multiplicity $3$. However, when I want to get the zeroes, with the same process above, we get
\begin{align*}
  -X^3-XZ^2-Z^3 &= 0
\end{align*}
which, to my knowledge and only has the solution $[0:1:0]$ as well, which doesn't really make any sense since $Y= 0$. I've tried a lot of methods to finding the rational points that satisfy the above equation, but I'm thinking I must've missed something in my definitions of the above terms that makes me believe that there might just be no zeros. I feel like this does not really work though because this divisor must have degree $0$.

I think that the point $[2:0:-1]$ still satisfies $X^3 - XZ^2 - Z^3 = 0$ over $GF(7)$, so you might have missed some zeros.

@ClemensB you are right, there was also definitely a typo in the original problem statement, we are checking for zeros of $-X^3-XZ^2-Z^3$ and I found my zeros after that. Thanks for giving me a sanity check

(This is answering the title question and not addressing the specific example  -- I haven't checked if there is an error in your computation.) Yes, this is definitely possible.
Consider the function $1 + x^2/y^2$ on $\mathbb{P^1}_{/\mathbb{R}}$. Then there are no $\mathbb{R}$-rational zeroes. The divisor of this function (which we compute after base change, i.e. in  $\mathbb{P^1}_{/\mathbb{C}}$) is the formal sum $([1: i]) + ([1: -i])  - 2([1:0])$.

(I'm not sure what text you're using or what sort of language it uses for talking about varieties over not algebraically closed fields -- the study of rational points is one of those things that makes the most sense in scheme language but which is often needed and introduced before scheme language for practical applications -- if this answer doesn't make sense let me know).

This is definitely helpful! My specific example had a typo in it that I've fixed and have been able to solve since. Thanks again for the insight, I have to work on my scheme theory for sure

Thanks -- and again you definitely don't need scheme theory for divisors on curves -- just need to be careful whether you are talking about the field of definition or its algebraic closure!
